# How to have different representations in Play based on an Accept header?

Tags: rest, playframework-2.1

Using Play Framework 2.1, and I'd like to make small variations in behavior based on the request's Accept header.  The only thing I can figure to do is this:

conf/routes

```
GET  /widgets  controllers.WidgetController.getWidgets()
```

WidgetController.java

```
public class LoginController extends Controller {
  public static Result loginUser() {
    if (ctx().request().headers().get("Accept")[0].equals("application/json")) {
      // ... json-specific logic
    }

    // common processing code

    if (ctx().request().headers().get("Accept")[0].equals("application/json")) {
      return ok();
    } else {
      return redirect(...);
    }
  }
}
```

Seems very nasty and procedural.  Any suggestions on the idiomatic "Play" way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if `request().accepts("application/json“)` but checking with if-else for every content-type seems to be [the standard way](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaContentNegotiation).

Comment: I wish Play had something like JAX-RS where I could annotate what it produces/consumes.